# Venustheme Megamenu - Cat page left-side doesn't work on mobile

Tags: magento2, menu, mobile, megamenu

I've got the Venustheme Mega Menu for **Magento 2**, and I've created a menu for the main menu, that works fine, on both desktop and mobile.

Now I've created another **menu**, for the **category page**, on the **left-side** part. The menu works fine on desktop, shows the categories and on hover also the subcategories.

The **issue** is on mobile, it shows the categories, but when I click on the + icon to drop down and see the subcategories, doesn't drop down, but just sends me to that category page.

I've tried all the configurations that the extension offer for mobile, and none drops down the menu.

Comment: Did you check in the console if you have some JS error ?

Comment: Yes already checked, no error while loading, no error on clicking, no error at all..

Comment: CSS also ? maybe you have some display none or overrided class etc...

Comment: Nothing like that, and even if would be so, it doesn't explain why it goes to that category page, instead of opening the subcats. It should do nothing in that case..

Comment: Sorry but I have more idea, without seeing the code and what you did, it's complicated for us to help you, try to contact the editor or share the code

Answer (score 0):

Best,

Same issue here.
If the **V** button or so called Nav Tab is pressed the menu folds out.
If the same menu item is pressed in another place not on the **V** Nav Tab the category opens. Which is very confusing to customers.

We use Porto theme for magento 2 with MegaMenu.
If i open my site in chrome and i inspect it with Ctrl+Shift+i and then
Ctrl+Shift+M You can test mobile version. [HTTPS://kbmodelcars.com](http://HTTPS://kbmodelcars.com)

Best regards.